# How does commit work in MySQL cluster?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using Mysql cluster 7.2 NDB. According to Wiki [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster#Hybrid_Storage),

> MySQL Cluster writes Redo logs to disk for all data changes as well as check pointing data to disk regularly. This allows the cluster to consistently recover from disk after a full cluster outage. As the Redo logs are written asynchronously with respect to transaction commit, some small number of transactions can be lost if the full cluster fails, however this can be mitigated by using geographic replication or multi-site cluster discussed above.

**Is it true?**

**Can somebody explain how exactly the commit works?** If the commit is not persisted into disk, it is mentioned that we'll lose some of the transactions. This behavior is not acceptable for my application.

**Is there any workaround for this issue?**

Comment: Are you asking how commit works in general or how the specific implementation for cluster works?

Comment: @N.B. how specifically it works for Mysql cluster?

Comment: A commit means that the operation succeeded and that OS is instructed to force HDD to physically save the record (no buffering). When every single server in the cluster commits the data to the disk, then the commit is considered successful. However, some computers might commit the transaction and some might not and then the outage occurs. That means that redo logs are used to recover the proper state. That means if your *entire* cluster fails at the point when each OS instructing HDDs to persist the data - you'll lose some transactions.

Comment: @N.B. i checked the scenerio (by crashing the data node as soon as a txn is commited) and found that the commit is successful but itsn't persisted to data node.

Comment: Did you disable write caching on your node's HDD?